# How do I pass dateTime type arrays from .NET to Delphi using unmanaged export (Robert Giesecke)?

Tags: c#, arrays, delphi, datetime

I want to pass dateTime type arrays from .NET dll to Delphi .
This is the c# code :

```
[DllExport]
public static void ReadDateTimeData(out IntPtr unmanagedArray, out int length)
{
    //Get the DateTimeArray
    DateTime[] dateTimeArray = MyClass.Instance.GetDateTimeArray();
    length = dateTimeArray.Length;

    unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length*Marshal.SizeOf(typeof (int)));
    Marshal.Copy(dateTimeArray, 0, unmanagedArray, length);
}
```

But the Marshal.Copy() method does not support DateTime type array to an unmanaged memory pointer. What should i do? In addition, How to implement the delphi code?

Comment: You need to agree on a date interop type. C# DateTime is different from Delphi TDateTime. You could convert C# to a Double equivalent to a Delphi date time. If it were me I'd probably go for a 64 bit integer with Unix time.

Comment: Can you not simply pass a marshalled array of strings and convert back to dates on the delphi side?

Comment: @toby that would be possible but represent dates as strings is somewhat inelegant. Plus arrays of strings are harder to marshal than arrays of value types.

Comment: [ISO8601](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) should be used for interop when passing around date/time values as strings.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your datetime values are within the Automation-compatible range you can use [`DateTime.ToOADate()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate(v=vs.110).aspx) to get the automation-compatible values and then simply use the overload of `Marshal.Copy` with `double[]` instead:

```
public static void ReadDateTimeData(out IntPtr unmanagedArray, out int length)
{
    // Get the DateTimeArray
    DateTime[] dateTimeArray = GetDateTimeArray();
    length = dateTimeArray.Length;
    // Convert to double[]
    double[] oaDateArray = new double[length];
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
        oaDateArray[i] = dateTimeArray[i].ToOADate();

    unmanagedArray = Marshal.AllocHGlobal(length * Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(double)));
    Marshal.Copy(oaDateArray, 0, unmanagedArray, length);
}
```

On the Delphi side, you will receive a pointer to a `TDateTime` array:

```
procedure ReadDateTimeData(out DateTimeArray: PDateTime; out Length: Integer); stdcall; external 'TestLib.dll';
procedure FreeDateTimeData(DateTimeArray: PDateTime); stdcall; external 'TestLib.dll';

procedure Main;
var
  DateTimeArray, P: PDateTime;
  I, Len: Integer;
begin
  ReadDateTimeData(DateTimeArray, Len);
  try
    P := DateTimeArray;
    for I := 0 to Len - 1 do
    begin
      Writeln(DateTimeToStr(P^));
      Inc(P);
    end;
  finally
    FreeDateTimeData(DateTimeArray);
  end;
end;
```

Or, with range checking off:

```
type
  PDateTimeArray = ^TDateTimeArray;
  TDateTimeArray = array[0..0] of TDateTime;

procedure ReadDateTimeData(out DateTimeArray: PDateTimeArray; out Length: Integer); stdcall; external 'TestLib.dll';
procedure FreeDateTimeData(DateTimeArray: PDateTimeArray); stdcall; external 'TestLib.dll';

procedure Main;
var
  DateTimeArray: PDateTimeArray;
  I, Len: Integer;
begin
  ReadDateTimeData(DateTimeArray, Len);
  try
    for I := 0 to Len - 1 do
      Writeln(DateTimeToStr(DateTimeArray^[I]));
  finally
    FreeDateTimeData(DateTimeArray);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: This is a good approach. FWIW `FreeDateTimeData` doesn't need to be exported. You can simply call `LocalFree` on the Delphi side because `Marshal.AllocHGlobal` is simply a call to `LocalAlloc`.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks, that's interesting. But the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5cyb68cy(v=vs.110).aspx) says _"Return Value: A pointer to the newly allocated memory. This memory must be released using the Marshal.FreeHGlobal method."_

Comment: The remarks say: *This method exposes the Win32 LocalAlloc function from Kernel32.dll.* It is intended to be used for interop so it is useful to know which shared heap it is allocated from. The other option is `Marshal.CoTaskMemAlloc` which allocates off the COM heap. Accordingly you can use COM's `CoTaskMemAlloc` and `CoTaskMemFree` and other COM heap methods to alloc/dealloc such memory.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Yes but since they so explicitly require the use of `Marshal.FreeHGlobal` I wonder if the CLR does something in addition to calling `LocalAlloc`, e.g. to keep track of allocated memory internally. Just guessing, though. I'd prefer to export another function just in case.

Comment: No, it's a straight wrapper around `LocalAlloc`. The whole point of it is that it is a shared heap. If the CLR did more then it would be next to useless. Export a function if you prefer, I'm just pointing this out in case you didn't already know it.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Thanks for pointing it out. The [reference code](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/runtime/interopservices/marshal.cs) shows you're right, it's just a call to `LocalAlloc`.